# Can't Autowire ServletContext

Tags: spring

I'm new with Spring, and I'm trying to use the @Autowire annotation for the ServletContext with my class attribute:

```
@Controller
public class ServicesImpl implements Services{

    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;
```

I defined the bean for this class in my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="services" class="com.xxx.yyy.ServicesImpl" />
```

But when I try to run a JUnit test it gives the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.servlet.ServletContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I thought that the ServletContext injection was automatic with spring... How can I solve this?

Thanks!

EDIT: I want to use the servletContext to call the getRealPath() method. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Implement the [ServletContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html) interface and Spring will inject it for you

```
@Controller
public class ServicesImpl implements Services, ServletContextAware{


private ServletContext context;

public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
     this.context = servletContext;
}
```

Comment: Yes, If it s from JUNit, you should use MockServletContext

Comment: Sorry for deleting the post, I defined the MockServletContext bean in my test-context.xml but the variable is still null...

Comment: Are you loading the test-context.xml?

Comment: Well, in my test class I used the `@ContextConfiguration("test-context.xml")` annotation, is that it?

Comment: Yes, that s it. Have you put you @Autowired back?

Comment: In Junit you just have to annotate the test class with @WebAppConfiguration (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/web/WebAppConfiguration.html) and the servletcontext will be injected, you can remove the autowired on the servletContext attribute too.

Answer (score 10):

You'll probably want to take a look at [MockServletContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockServletContext.html) which can be used in unit tests.

Comment: But how do I use it? Should I just define the bean in my test-context.xml like this: `<bean class="org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext"/>` ?

Comment: I defined it and I'm not getting any errors anymore but the context variable is null...

Comment: If you use the code below, a MockServletContext is created for you and you will be able to use @ Autowired on your ServletContext field.
@ RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ WebAppConfiguration
@ ContextConfiguration(classes = { WebSpringConfiguration.class })

Answer (score 3):

`ServletContext` is not a Spring bean and it can, therefore, not be injected unless you implement [`ServletContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html).

If one thinks in modules or layers then the servlet context shouldn't be available outside the web module/layer. I suppose your `ServicesImpl` forms part of the business or service layer.

If you gave a little more context we might be able to suggest better alternatives.

Comment: Hi Marcel, I'm trying to use it so I can call the getRealPath method to get the root directory. How else can I accomplish this? THanks!