# How do i create ServletContext in Spring

Tags: spring

I wanted to add some values to the servletcontext, but am not sure how to get the object in spring. Can anyone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;
```

Comment: That didnt work... is there some kind of sample code you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895728/cant-autowire-servletcontext).

Implementing the **ServletContextAware** interface will make Spring to inject the context.

```
@Controller
public class ServicesImpl implements Services, ServletContextAware{


private ServletContext context;

public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
     this.context = servletContext;
}
```