# Unsatisfied Dependency Exception in creating beans using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use JPA for my spring application. I have integrated the JPATransactionManager & LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean into AppConfig class. Now, when I try to call one of the method which is in DaoImpl, the AppConfig is not able to Autowire the classes. Here is my code

```
Test Class

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = 
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

      BbDao personService = context.getBean(BbDao.class);
      personService.getDealByDealId("0194541605021NJMAPFU");
      context.close();
   }
}
```

### AppConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.bb.spring")
public class AppConfig{

 @Bean
   public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
      LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("MyPersistence");
      return factoryBean;
   }

   @Bean
   public JpaTransactionManager geJpaTransactionManager() {
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
      return transactionManager;
   }

}
```

### ConfirmPurchaseController

```
@RestController
public class ConfirmPurchaseController {

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ConfirmPurchaseController.class);

@Autowired
private MyService myService;

@GetMapping("/purchase")
public ResultDto confirmpurchase(HttpServletResponse response) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    // Business Logic    
}
}
```

### MyService

```
@Component
public interface MyService {
    // Methods defined
}
```

### MyServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService, ServletContextAware {

private ServletContext servletContext;

public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    this.servletContext = servletContext;
}

public ServletContext getServletContext() {
    return servletContext;
}


// Added the implemented methods of the MyService Interface
}
```

The exception it throws is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'servletContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

and the error log is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'confirmPurchaseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'servletContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
at net.bb.spring.controller.Test.main(Test.java:14)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'servletContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
... 14 more

 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
... 27 more
```

Any ideas would be very helpful for me.

P.S : Im using configuration as annotations, no XML

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895728/cant-autowire-servletcontext

Comment: Coud you share myService class ?

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid, updated with myService class

Comment: @JackFlamp, I have added ServletContext and a setter method in my MyServiceImpl and added implements ServletContextAware, but still the error is same

Comment: He means the implementing MyServiceImpl. Add the code for that class

Comment: @JackFlamp Updated with MyServiceImpl

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid Updated with MyServiceImpl

Comment: @Yakhoob have you tried to autowire ServletContext like `@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;`? In the examples I have seen they do it in the Controller class

Comment: Yes Jack. I have tried that also. Still the same

Comment: As you are implementing `ServletContextAware`, Spring will inject `ServletContext` for you. Remove `@Autowired` from `ServletContext`.

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar, followed your answer, but still this is the error Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'confirmPurchaseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'servletContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=tru

Comment: Why is it pointing to ConfirmPurchaseController?

Comment: Because your controller has a service layer object `MyService` and creation of this service layer object is failing, due to which, the creation of controller object is failing.

Comment: Okay. But how to fix this one? :(

Comment: I observe, you have a  method called `setContext()` which takes a `ServletContext`. This method should have `@Autowired` rather than the direct field. And the method name should be `setServletContext()`, since you are trying to auto bind with the fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156250/discussion-between-yakhoob-and-shyam-baitmangalkar).

Comment: I don't know but I don't like `@Component` and `@Service` in `MyService` and `MyServiceImpl`. Just keep `@Service` and remove the other one and add do it like this `@Service('MyService')`

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid tried even that.. Same issue

Answer (score 0):

It is not an answer, however I cannot add a comment yet.

Did you try to autowire a ServletContext via setter method?
- remove @Autowired from property
- remove one of your setters for context (unnecessary duplication)
- mark a setter as @Autowired

Moreover remove @Component annotation from MyService, it is unnecessary if you are using @Service annotation in its implementation.

Comment: I do not recommend using field/setter injection. This might give you problems in the future. Best practice is to use constructor injection.

Comment: @Staszko Now which one to follow?

Comment: @Staszko, you can see that in my code that I have used ServletContext for my Impl class. I tried your way also. But still same error

Comment: Try it anyway with `public void setContext(ServletContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}` setter, remove previous one and check if it works. Remember about that unnecessary @Component in MyService.

It would give us information, if setter injection works.

Comment: I have removed @Component in MyService and added the setContext in my Impl class with Autowired annotation.  But Im getting this error Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'confirmPurchaseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'servletContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Answer (score 0):

As per Apache Tomcat documentation, a `ServletContext`

> Defines a set of methods that a servlet uses to communicate with its
>   servlet container.
>
> There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine.
>   (A "web application" is a collection of servlets and content installed
>   under a specific subset of the server's URL namespace such as /catalog
>   and possibly installed via a .war file.)

Which means that a ServletContext is only valid within a Servlet Container like Apache Tomcat. But as I can see, you are trying to run a normal Java application by creating beans in a main method, which makes the existence of `ServletContext` invalid.

So what you have to do is:

STEP 1: Build your AppConfig and override required methods.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"net.bb.spring"})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
        }

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/");
        }
        //....
    }
```

STEP 2: Create WebInitializer to initialize Dispatcher Servlet

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

STEP 3: Create your Service layer to autowire ServletContext

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Autowire
    public MyServiceImpl(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    public ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return servletContext;
    }

    //...
}
```

STEP 4: Build your application to a WAR file

STEP 5: Deploy your WAR file to webapp folder of Tomcat (If you are using Tomcat)

STEP 6: Start Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to change:

1) You don't need to annotate the interface with `@Component`, annotation is required only on the implementation class

**MyService**

```
public interface MyService {
    // Methods defined
}
```

2) Use constructor injection to obtain an instance of `ServeletContext`.

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService, ServletContextAware {
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Autowire
    public MyServiceImpl(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }



    //TODO: other methods goes here...
}
```

pay attention that `ServletContext` is not a Spring bean and it can, therefore, not be injected unless you implement `ServletContextAware`. keep your implementation class `implements` `ServletContextAware`