# Not able to load servlet context in Spring

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servletcontextlistener

I'm trying to load the properties data on server startup. For this I have created a class that implements `ServletContextListener`. This will load all the properties.

And in my DaoImpl class, I'm trying to get the properties data and get initialized to some of the strings. But it throws the exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bbService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bbService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BBDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-web-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.bb.dao.BBDaoImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is my Config class

```
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

private static final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "config";
private Properties config = new Properties();

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event){
    try {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/uat.properties");
        config = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            throw new QiibException("Loading config failed");
        } catch (QiibException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    event.getServletContext().setAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, this);
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
}

public static Config getInstance(ServletContext context) {
    return (Config) context.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
}

public String getProperty(String key) {
    return config.getProperty(key);
}
}
```

The DAOImpl class is

```
public class BBDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements BBDao, ServletContextAware  {

Properties properties = null;

@Autowired
private ServletContext ctx; 


public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    this.ctx = servletContext;
}

public BBDaoImpl() throws IOException {
    super();
    Config config = Config.getInstance(ctx); --> ctx is null here.
```

What is wrong here?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that's right, how it can be any other way. 1) you create object => constructor call 2)  because you have `ServletContextAware` you get context with `setServletContext` call. Basically you can't set context without of an instance of an object, so constructor call will always come first

Comment: Put `@Repository` annotation on your `BBDaoImpl` class.

Comment: @SandipSolanki, it throws org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.qiib.dao.BBDao' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: BBDaoImpl,BBDAO.. I already have <bean id="BBDAO" class="com.qiib.dao.BBDaoImpl">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>

Comment: @varren, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Why? Why do you want to tie your DB layer to your web layer (which is what you are effectively doing with this). Instead use Spring to load the properties file with `@PropertySource` and use `@Value` or the `Environment` class to access the properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your exception, you will find that there is nested exception in your service class where it is trying to autowired the dao bean which is still not initialized.

first look at your configuration:- 
1. are you scanning your dao Repo.
2. if yes are putting any stereotype(@Component) in your Dao class.

please look on these you will find your solution in your exception itself.

Comment: Ravat, I'm scanning DAO too and I tried to keep @Component, but still the ctx is getting as null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895728/cant-autowire-servletcontext
this link can you help you

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that you just want to get some properties and initialize your class,why don't achieve this in a spring way

1. put your properties in spring property file , and make `BBDaoImpl`  implement `EnvironmentAware` interface and `InitializingBean` interface,then you can initialize `BBDaoImpl` in `afterPropertiesSet` method  declared in `InitializingBean`.The key process is implementing `EnvironmentAware` ,thus you get the reference of environment object, by which you can  get your properties
2. Or you can implement `ServletConfigAware`, it's similar to the above